# Crashing when testing

Tags: java, android

So, I've just started views and moving between activities. I thought I got what I was looking for. I fixed all my errors, but now when I test the application it crashes. I'm new to android and eclipse. So I'm not exactly sure what's happening. Here's my MainActivity.java:

```
       import android.os.Bundle;
       import android.app.Activity;
       import android.content.Intent;
       import android.util.Log;
       import android.view.Menu;
       import android.view.MenuInflater;
       import android.view.View;
       import android.widget.Button;
       import android.widget.EditText;
       import android.widget.TextView;

    public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String info = intent.getStringExtra("info_key");
    TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.nametext);
    text.setText(info);
}


//opens a new activity.
public void openAddItem (View v){
    Intent intent = new Intent (this, Additem.class);
    startActivity(intent);
      }

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}

    }
```

And here's my second activity; Additem.java:

```
    package com.grocerylist;

     import android.os.Bundle;
     import android.app.Activity;
     import android.content.Intent;
     import android.view.Menu;
     import android.view.View;
     import android.widget.EditText;
     import android.widget.TextView;

    public class Additem extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_additem);

}


public void additem (View v){
    EditText text = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.itemname);
    String info = text.getText().toString();
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("info_key", info);
    startActivity(intent);
     }


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_additem, menu);
    return true;
}

    }
```

Thanks, and I'm positive the problem lies where I've placed my id's.

Comment: Post your logcat. In fact, once you find your logcat, there's a good chance, you can fix it yourself ;)

Comment: where do you call the openAdditem() method and why are you passing a view to it? Which Activity starts when you launch the app? Please post some LogCat output. If you don't have the LogCat visible yet, go to Window - Show View - LogCat

Comment: Yes, it just shows where the problem is. Line 28 which is in my MainActivity.java, but i'm not seeing the problem with: text.setText(info). Do you? @323go

Comment: The problem is that either `text` or `info` are null. Find out which one.

Comment: your info String is null 'cause there's no Intent to get

Answer (score 1):

Your first problem I see is here

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
    String info = intent.getStringExtra("info_key");
    TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.nametext);
    text.setText(info);
```

there is no `Intent` to "get" if this is your first `Activity`. That is used when you start an `Activity` with an `Intent` and send `extras`. So, naturally, `info` is `null`. There will be something there when you create it from your second `Activity` but not when you first run your app. Also, you may want to check into using [startActivityForResult](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html) in your first `Activity`

Second, I don't see where you call `openAddItem()` in your first `Activity`. It may be from a `Button` but I don't see any `Buttons`

It looks like you are missing some key understandings of the fundamentals of the Android framework. I suggest you start with the [Docs Here](http://developer.android.com/training/index.html) if you haven't been through them already. Good luck to you

Also, this

```
Intent intent = new Intent (this, Additem.class);
```

should be this

```
Intent intent = new Intent (MainActivity.this, Additem.class);
```

Comment: @KyleK I'm glad I could help! Kindly accept as the right answer and others with similar problems will find it easier

Answer (score -2):

the first problem I also see was already mentioned by *codeMagic*.

The second thing: in case you just call your methods which start another `Activity` in `onCreate()`, you will get a pseudo-infinite number of those `Activities` in the stack and your app will crash.

Consider watching [these tutorials](http://thenewboston.org/list.php?cat=6), it may help you to get started